# how to integrate the generated link by wunderground.com into my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, weather-api

in fact I am a beginner in the field of API and this is the first time I registered on wunderground.com, and I follow the documentation to generate the key ID. later I found links and codes.

[Forecast in French](http://api.wunderground.com/api/2ea138a9dd52eabe/forecast/lang%3aFR/q/France/Paris.json)

PHP:

```
<?php $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/2ea138a9dd52eabe    /geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
$temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n"; ?>
```

Javascript & Jquery:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $.ajax({
 url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/2ea138a9dd52eabe/geolookup/conditions  /q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json", dataType : "jsonp", success : function(parsed_json) {
 var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
 var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
 alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
 } }); }); </script>
```

Have a wonderful day

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but I noticed that the code doesn't work unless the spaces are removed from the ajax URL.

Comment: thank you for response, my question is how to integrate the generated link or code by wunderground.com into my website .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wunderground can be integrated using differend kind of methods.

You have provide two separated ones: one from PHP and another from JavaScript.
Both are equivalent, but implemented in different technologies.

## Javascript

You can use JavaScript snipplet to load forecast on-the-fly. This way you have to insert fetched data in DOM hierarchy in place, where you need it. Replace your alert() call with something more appropriate. E.g.:

```
$("#weather").empty().append ("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
```

You should create block/inline-element with "weather" id somewhere in document:

```
<div id="weather">Loading forecast...</div>
```

## PHP

Another way is to insert weather data from PHP side. This way you should output forecast directly into div:

```
<div id="weather"><?php "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n"; ?></div>
```

Comment: thank you Greshnik for support .